# dueChange event for duet picker not working with Ionic 5 / Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, datepicker

I am using [Duet Date Picker](https://github.com/duetds/date-picker) in the Ionic 5/ Vue 3 application. The event listener for the [duetChange](https://github.com/duetds/date-picker#events) is not working for me.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<duet-date-picker @duetChange="handleInput($event)"identifier="date" :localization.prop="localisation" direction="left"></duet-date-picker>


handleInput(e: any) {
      console.log("e", e);
      this.$emit("input", this.content);
    }
```

I have even tried following listners:

```
v-on:duetChange="handleInput($event)" 

v-on:change="handleInput($event)" 

@change="handleInput($event)"
```

Is this the right way to add an event listener or am I missing something?

Here is the code sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/old-silence-1f0nx?file=/src/App.vue

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the duetDatePicker in a Vue CodeSandbox, the following works:

```
<duet-date-picker
  @duetChange="handleInput"
  identifier="date"
  :localization.prop="localisation_uk"
>
```

Along with the above, my methods object contained the `handleInput` function declaration.

[image: Edit vigorous-surf-9uyil]

Check the `App.vue` file in the codesandbox for details.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I think this one is for Vue 2, checkout my CodeSandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/old-silence-1f0nx?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: whats not working? @AdityaSharma when i click your codesandbox link i can select a date please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work the old fashion way...

```
    onMounted(() => {
      // Select the date picker component
      const date = document.getElementById("date-picker");

      // Listen for when date is selected
      date.addEventListener("duetChange", function (e) {
        console.log("selected date", e.detail.valueAsDate);
      });
    });
```

```
  <duet-date-picker id="date-picker"
    @duetChange="handleInput"
    identifier="date"
    :localization.prop="localisation_uk"
  >
```